# Data not updating in SQL databse by PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Well I am new to coding,What I am trying is to update data in database through Php .I am trying hard to update data but i don't know where is problem coming ,there is no error too.My first file is

```
"ppp.html"

<html>
<form action="l.php"method="post">

<input type ="text" name ="complaint">

</input>
<input type="submit"></input>

</html>
```

Now my "L.php " 
It also don't show any error .It goes through easily

```
<?php
        $complaint="";
        if(    
       isset($_POST['complaint']))
       {$complaint =$_POST['complaint'];}

mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("couldnt attack ");
mysql_select_db("site")or die('i surrender');
$query=("SELECT * FROM site2 where category='$complaint'") or die("couldnt select");
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ('hghyt');
while ($complaint= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{



              echo"<td>".'<br>'.$complaint['category']."</tr>";
              ECHO"<TR>"."<A HREF='update.php'>"."UPDATE"."</A>";


             echo "<br/>";
             ECHO"</table>";


    }        
    ?>
```

Sorry for very wrong query and very inappropriate way of coding but I am learning it all by myself through internet 
Now my "update.php file"

```
<html>
<form action="update1.php" method="post">
<input type= "text" name="blue"></input>
<input type= "submit"></input>
</form>
</html>
```

It also goes of in easy way,and don't show any problem ,now my last file "update1.php"

```
<?php
$complaint="";
 if(isset ($_POST['complaint']))
 {$complaint =$_POST['complaint'];}

$blue="";
 if(isset ($_POST['blue']))
 {$blue =$_POST['blue'];}
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("couldnyt coibnovdbs");
mysql_select_db("site") or die ("no databse");
$query=("update site2 set category='$blue' where category ='$complaint'") or die ("couldnt attack");
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("kjkk");
?>
```

Please help me .It is bothering me,I cant find any solution for it.I think problem is in last file only but it is not showing any errors.

Thank you

Comment: If you change the query to a variable and check if you execute the query through PhpMyAdmin, does it update the table correctly?

`$tmpQuery = "update site2 set category='$blue' where category ='$complaint'"; echo $tmpQuery`;

Comment: if I execute query through phpMyAdmin it updates correctly ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the flow of your website, `update1.php` never receives the value in `$complaint`, hence fails to update. You need to pass the value to it.

For example, the following edits should suffice.

Edit L.php

```
echo"<td>".'<br>'.$complaint['category']."</tr>";
ECHO"<TR>"."<A HREF='update.php?complaint=".$complaint['category']."'>"."UPDATE"."</A>";
```

Edit update.php

```
<html>
<form action="update1.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="complaint" value="<?php echo $_GET['complaint'] ?>"
<input type= "text" name="blue"></input>
<input type= "submit"></input>
</form>
</html>
```